# PHP Convert hex to cyrillic string

Tags: php, hex, decode

I'm struggling to convert a CSV filled with hex rows. Here are the contents of one row:

```
c8ece520ede020e4e0edfaf7edee20e7e0e4faebe6e5edee20ebe8f6e5
```

How to convert this into a Cyrillic string? If I run in through an online [converter](https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter) and [decoder](https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) it correctly converts this text, encoded as CP-1251:

> **Име на данъчно задължено лице**

But how to do it from PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hex2bin()` will convert to binary characters, and then use `mb_convert_encoding()` to get it into standard Unicode text.

```
$hex = "c8ece520ede020e4e0edfaf7edee20e7e0e4faebe6e5edee20ebe8f6e5";
$bin = hex2bin($hex);
$text = mb_convert_encoding($bin, 'utf-8', 'cp1251');
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
Име на данъчно задължено лице
```